# How to find the matching subsequence that maximizes the sum of cost

Tags: algorithms

Let $T$ and $P$ be two sequences $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ and $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$. It is easy to design an $O(n)$ algorithm to determine whether $P$ is a subsequent. Now assume that the $i$th character of $T$ has a positive cost $c(i)$ associated with it. Find the matching subsequence that maximizes the sum of cost. That is, find the sequence of indices $1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_k\le n$ such that for all $j$, $1\le j\le k$, we have ${{t}_{{{i}_{j}}}}=p_j$, and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{c\left( {{i}_{j}} \right)}$ is maximized.

I can design an $O(n^2)$ algorithm. Is it possible to design a faster algorithm?

Comment: You mean lower computational complexity?

Comment: @mathreadler If $O(n^2)$ is the lower computational complexity, prove it. If not, give a faster algorithm.